# The most efficient way to build user interfaces for web using .Net

Tags: .net

Considering **developer's perspective**,
what's the most efficient way to create, maintain, and improve a complex Web UI.

I'm familiar with a bunch of toolkits like ext.net, telerik, devx. Silverlight is also an option to consider.

What would you recommend to me?

Comment: What is your target audience? General internet application or enterprise application?

Comment: Is it a line-of-business application? Since you're deploying within a closed network environment (essentially), Silverlight would be Microsoft's recommended technology.

Comment: What's about the niceties for visual designing UI using Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this mostly deals with the general architecture of your system.  Two things to keep in mind would be

Separation of concerns - make sure the presentation layer is only concerned with presentation

and

Modularization - create discrete, testable modules (controls)

Whatever you go with (MVC, webforms, silverlight), a good architecture will make UI maintenance more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC is pretty hot right now.

Silverlight is good as long as you can be sure that your users will install the plugin if needed. If it is an enterprise app, rather than a public facing website, then you are probably fine.

It's really your call, there aren't distinct advantages to either that I can think of.

Comment: What's about a visual GUI for ASP.NET MVC development?

Answer (score 0):

MVC 3 with KnockoutJS for MVVM in the client is a very nice way to go with a nice degree of separation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ASP.NET MVC for two enterprise project and I love to take all control of UI with MVC. Your are totally free and you can do whetever you want because you are creating your own HTML. Despite of writing all HTML by hand It was quickly completed than Silverlight project I have worked.

Comment: What's about a visual GUI for ASP.NET MVC development?

Comment: Visual Studio supports Visual development for ASP.NET MVC but if you know HTML well I think you dont need a visual designer. Firebug is your friend.